# consuming json webservice in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I am making a windows phone app which can consume json from this link http://dir.yummly.com/4/public/8a753a70358c827b01358da787bd68f3 , however when i try to download data asynchronously , i am unable to get e.result in a readable language.
here is my c# code --

```
    Uri sub4 = new Uri("http://dir.yummly.com/4/public/8a753a70358c827b01358da787bd68f3");
        string kit = sub4.ToString();
    WebClient w = new WebClient();
        w.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
        w.DownloadStringAsync(sub4);
        MessageBox.Show("done");

        }
    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    string fres = e.Result;// here e.result was � 
    }
```

And then I want to deserialize e.result.
 My code is working properly for any other json url. And since I am working on windows phone app so I am unable to use other webcilent methods such as DownloadData and DownloadString. Also i have seen many conversions between utf8 and unicode  but none of them worked. Can anyone please help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API you are hitting serves gzipped content, and that is what you are seeing as garbage text. You need to unzip the content before using it. You can tell this from the header:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Unfortunately, the last time I checked, there was no built in support for GZip'ed responses in Windows Phone. It should not be too hard to create a workaround. When googling, results suggests that the lowest impact solution is adding the [SharpGIS.GZipWebClient](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpGIS.GZipWebClient) library from NuGet and use the GZip support from there.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. You are great..!! And for those who are having same problem can refer to this link-- http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.in/2012/01/json-deserialization-with-jsonnet.html